# Error dereferencing an iterator in C++ Set and Vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator, set

I'm writing this code and I'm getting this error:

> [Error] passing 'const std::vector' as 'this' argument of 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = metastock7, _Alloc = std::allocator, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = metastock7]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

```
struct A{
     string name;
     vector<B> rows;
};
set<A, classcomp> set;
vector<B> data; //I filled the vector in my code
std::set<A, classcomp>::iterator it;
std::pair<std::set<A, classcomp>::iterator,bool> ret;
for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
    A a;
    B b = data[i];
    a.name= b.name;
    ret = set.insert(a);
    it = ret.first;
    (*it).rows.push_back(b); //IT COMPILES WITHOUT
    // it->rows.push_back(mstk7); //fails as well
}
```

I really don't understand the error. Can you please help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::set` is an ordered container, so it doesn't allow you to directly modify its elements. If it did, you could invalidate its ordering guarantees.

To modify the element, you'd need to copy it, erase it from the set, modify it, then reinsert it. If you find yourself needing to do this often, you might want to consider using a different container type, especially as copying your `std::vector` member could get expensive.

Comment: Maybe using a `map` would be more ideal

Comment: Thank you! I choose set only because it doesn't allow duplicates. Are there other containers that don't allow duplicates?

Comment: As @OlivierPoulin says, you might be better off with a map between `name` and `rows`. Have a look at [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) and [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: @user3665096 Well, there's std::unordered_set, but it doesn't allow to modify its objects either unfortunately, since its objects are ordered by their hash value, which usually depends on the state of the object. So much for being "unordered".

Comment: And if you don't want to change your design a lot, nothing stops you from having an std::map<std::string, A> with A::name as the key. As long as you don't plan on changing the name of A through the map, it should be fine